# How receive hook from Bitbucket on JIRA and process this hook data?

Tags: triggers, bitbucket, jira, webhooks

How receive hook from Bitbucket on JIRA and process this hook data?

I can't figure out how to properly create a hook listener from Bitbucket to JIRA.

As I can see:

1) There is a branch in Bitbucket

2) A commit is added to the branch and a Pull Request is created.

3) The reviewer clicks Approve at Pull Request and at this moment a change in the status of the task should occur in JIRA, which in one of the fields contains the name of the branch

I understand how to send a hook from BitBucket, but how to get a hook and process it in JIRA

I do not understand how to implement this, have any ideas?

Comment: Bitbucket Server or Bitbucket Cloud? Jira Server or Jira Cloud? Have you linked the two?

Comment: @JimRedmond,  All as server, jira has integration with bitbucket. To be honest, the problem is already a bit different)
The "JIRA Automation" plugin is installed in the JIRA, the end point is configured in it for accepting an external webhook, the BitBucket is configured to send a webhook to JIRA, but the JIRA requires authorization, how to authorize the BitBucket hook to me is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, it's simple via WebHooks
I used the plugin JIRA Automation

1. Bitbucket sends the hook to the JIRA with the transfer of the secret
   (basic authorization);
2. JIRA gets the hook and processes the hook
   using the plugin
3. JIRA then sends a request to TeamCity to build a
   specific branch using a plugin;
4. TeamCity is building a specific branch and sends the hook
   to JIRA, and JIRA processes the hook from the
   TeamCity and performs the actions